# Jquery to Make 2 Sets of Radio Buttons Mirror Eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to setup two sets of radio buttons that will function simultaneously.  In other words whenever Male is checked on the top, I would like Male at the bottom to be automatically checked.  (and vice versa)  If user scrolls down and clicks female then the one at the top should be checked.   No matter which radio the user clicks both radio sets should always have the same value checked.   Please advise on the most practical way to accomplish this.  My main focus is Javascript or Jquery but I have spent several hours trying to come up with something to no avail.  Please advise.   Thanks!  :)

```
<div class="top">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" checked="checked" /> Female<br />
</div>

<div>Random Content</div>

<div class="bottom">
<input type="radio" name="sex2" value="Male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex2" value="Female" checked="checked" /> Female<br />
</div>
```

Comment: You can check a radio button with document.getElement_whatever_('the_button_id_classname_or_whatever').checked=true;    How did you spend HOURS trying to figure this out?

Comment: Other tasks it may take me minutes which would take you hours my friend.  :)    However your solution DOES work in this situation.    Thank you very much.  -K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an onclick listener to both sets. Like this:

```
document.getElementById("male1").onclick=clickMale;
document.getElementById("male2").onclick=clickMale;
document.getElementById("female1").onclick=clickFemale;
document.getElementById("female2").onclick=clickFemale;

function clickMale(){
  document.getElementById("male1").checked=true;
  document.getElementById("male2").checked=true;
}
function clickFemale(){
  document.getElementById("female1").checked=true;
  document.getElementById("female2").checked=true;
}
```

And add IDs to the radio buttons ("male1", "male2", "female1", "female2")

Answer (score 4):

Attach to the `change` event and selecting all other radio buttons which have the same beginning of the `name` and are of equal `value` but which are not the current one.

```
$("input[name^='sex']").change(function(){
    var $otherRadioButtons = $("input[name^='sex'][value='" + this.value + "']").not(this);
    $otherRadioButtons.prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

The above is not using any clever caching of the selectors which you can add yourself.

Basically, whenever a radio button changes it's checked value the code will select all **other** radio buttons with the same `value` (male/female) which also start with the same `name` (sex????) and set their checked property to the same value as the current one.

I hope this makes sense. See a working demo below.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtEpz/) - Changing radio buttons in a set.

**Edit**

> I just noticed.. I am using jquery 1.3.2 and upgrading isnt an option
>   at the moment. You don't happen to have a 1.3.2 alternative do you?

For jQuery version 1.3.2 use the `attr` method instead of the `prop` method:

```
$("input[name^='sex']").change(function(){
    var $otherRadioButtons = $("input[name^='sex'][value='" + this.value + "']").not(this);
    $otherRadioButtons.attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtEpz/1/) - Changing radio buttons in a set using jQuery 1.3.2.

Comment: VERY NICELY DONE.   Thanks a million Mr. Wahl!

Comment: @Nolan: You are wlecome, glad it helped.

Comment: I just noticed.. I am using jquery 1.3.2 and upgrading isnt an option at the moment.  You don't happen to have a 1.3.2 alternative do you?

Comment: @Nolan: No problem, use `attr` instead of the `prop` method. Check latest edit. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned it, Zove's answer in jQuery would be something like this, if you prefer:

```
$("#male1").click(clickMale);
$("#male2").click(clickMale);
$("#female1").click(clickFemale);
$("#female2").click(clickFemale);

function clickMale(){
    $("#male1").attr('checked', true);
    $("#male1").attr('checked', true);
}

function clickFemale(){
    $("#female1").attr('checked', true);
    $("#female2").attr('checked', true);
}
```

You don't need jQuery for something this simple, but if you're using it elsewhere, it's best to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense, to share a class for both male / female inputs, e.g. 'js-male' or 'js-female'). This saves some code. for instance you could do:

```
   $('.js-male').change(function() {
      $('.js-male').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
   });

   $('.js-female').change(function() {
     $('.js-female').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
   });
```

There might be more elegant ways to deal with the whole situation so. Do you really want the inputs to have different names ('male', 'male2'), which means that your server receives two different params? If you give both radio button groups the same names, only the value of the last one will be sent to the server, anyway, if you mirror the radio buttons anyway, this doesn't really matter.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VvT5f/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the location of your jQuery source and this will work right out of the box.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#male1, #male2").live("click", function(){
                $("#male1").attr("checked", $("#male2").attr("checked"));
                $("#male2").attr("checked", $("#male1").attr("checked"));
            });

            $("#female1, #female2").live("click", function(){
                $("#female1").attr("checked", $("#female2").attr("checked"));
                $("#female2").attr("checked", $("#female1").attr("checked"));
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <input id="male1" type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" /> Male<br />
        <input id="female1" type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" checked="checked" /> Female<br />
    </div>

    <div>Random Content</div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <input id="male2" type="radio" name="sex2" value="Male" /> Male<br />
        <input id="female2" type="radio" name="sex2" value="Female" checked="checked" /> Female<br />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This one seems to not work well when clicking back to the top male.  Demo http://jsfiddle.net/t2pPT/

Comment: Your example defaults to jQuery 1.3.2. Switch it to 1.7.3 or 1.8.0.