# Javascript validation of Adobe form (radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, validation, livecycle

I'm having difficulty (I'm new to JavaScript) figuring out a little validation in Adobe LiveCycle forms.  I have a first choice (4 option) radio button, 2nd choice (same 4 options) and 3rd choice (same 4 options) where I'd like a validation to make sure the user doesn't enter the same result 3 times.

I thought it would be something like:

```
event.rc = true;
if (  form1.#subform[0].FirstChoice.rawValue !=   form1.#subform[0].SecondChoice.rawValue ! &&  form1.#subform[0].FirstChoice.rawValue !=  form1.#subform[0].ThirdChoice.rawValue !)
{
    app.alert("You need three separate answers, you dimwit!");
    event.rc = false;
}
```

Evidently, I am being a dimwit and going about this all wrong, but I've drawn a blank.

I was thinking also along the lines of:

```
form1.#subform[0].FirstChoice.rawValue <>   form1.#subform[0].SecondChoice.rawValue ! &&  form1.#subform[0].FirstChoice.rawValue !<>  form1.#subform[0].ThirdChoice.rawValue !)
```

but I don't know where to go with it.

Help (please), thanks.

Comment: are you looking for simple java script code or something special that works with adobe form ?

Comment: I'm using Adobe Livecycle to make the form, so I was going to use JavaScript, but FormCalc is okay too I guess - I'm not an expert, so please be gentle.

Comment: I am suggesting you a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167336/jquery-to-make-2-sets-of-radio-buttons-mirror-eachother prepare your code according to this.

Comment: Can you clarify what question you're struggling with?  I can see two:
1) How do I detect the condition when two or more questions have the same answer?
2) How do I set up my validation to catch this case?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.  Try:

```
if ((Select1.rawValue != null && Select1.rawValue == Select2.rawValue) || (Select2.rawValue != null && Select2.rawValue == Select3.rawValue) || (Select3.rawValue != null && Select1.rawValue == Select3.rawValue))
{
    app.alert("You need three separate answers, you dimwit!");
}
```

You need to cover the case where the Selections are not yet filled in.  Select1, Select2, and Select3 are the RadioButton group.

I would put this as a calculation on a hidden field since you want it to recalculate whenever a change is made to the radio buttons.